# Delete rows that contains one or more strings from list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet in Excel with many lines with values. For each row on this sheet, Excel must check if its content matches **any** of the strings of another table. If it matches **one or more**, the row must be deleted.

Example:

```
Table 1 (delete criteria):
SP
MG
AC
SP
RR

Table 2 (table with content to be deleted):
special
São Paulo, SP
roraima
macapá
```

So, for each line of Table2, I must check if it contains **any** strings in Table 1. Also, the match must be case sensitive, and can occur in any position of table 2. So, the line with "special" will NOT be deleted, but the line with "São Paulo, SP" will.

How should be the excel formula to do so? Both tables are on the same sheet, but I can change that if it makes it easier.

Update: it has come to my attention that Excel does not delete rows, I need a script for this. In this case, it can mark the rows somehow or change formatting. Anything that signals that row as a "match."

Comment: `excel formula` don't delete rows.  You need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

For this question i use Sheet1:

[image]

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, Result As Long
    Dim Value1 As String, Value2 As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For i = 12 To 9 Step -1
            Value2 = .Range("A" & i).Value

            For j = 2 To 6
                Value1 = .Range("A" & j).Value
                Result = InStr(1, Value2, Value1)

                If Result > 1 Then
                    .Rows(i).Delete
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Need to qualify which sheet `Rows` is on as well.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, every correction is more than welcome. Thanks!. Could you please evaluate the code after correction?

Comment: The only other thing I can see (sorry, can't see the pic and haven't actually run the code) is that `InStr(1, Value2, Value1)` would find `SP` in `SPecial` but not in `special`.  Not sure how to get it to only look for whole words - could put a space in front/behind it but that wouldn't help if it's the first or last word in the text.  `FIND` only works on cells rather text string...